# Enable buttons when user read the disclaimer angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

Hi I have the following modal,

```
<div class="dialog-header">

        <div class="col-2 warning-image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-content" [innerHTML]="message | translate: messageData? messageData : null"></div>
<table>........</table>
<div>{{descalimer}}</div>
    <div class="dialog-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-dbs-solid"  (click)="confirm(false)">{{confirmBtn.text | translate}}</button>
    </div>
```

I can have the table to be too long and can be too short. The button should be shown all the time, but only enable once the user read the full table and the disclaimer. How to enable the button on full scrolldown in angular or javascript? any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't be evil nobody read it :)

Comment: Also how scrolling helps you if I can scroll in less then one second without reading how it will help you?:) You can add second step to check how long users spend on reading it :) Then you will be true evil

Comment: true. but thats what the user wants :)

Comment: no users wants to see button next and go further, if they wants to read message they will read it no matter button is enabled or not

Comment: Anyway if to be more serious then you need to check element.scrollTop